# Canvas "particles" increasing speed on ajax reload

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, canvas

I have a canvas item that has several variables determining the speed of the "particles" I am generating.  I have it setup so that when you log in the canvas updates and changes color(basically I am using a php session variable to reitterate the js code for the canvas to change a few variables on it) I am using ajax to reload the page with the canvas within the main page(so the whole page does not reload).  When ever it reloads the canvas page via ajax the speed of the particles increases.  When I reload with the reload button it does not increase.  Is there a way to reset the canvas in between the ajax(I have tried using canvas.delete("all"); and canvas.delete("speed"); but it continues to speed up the canvas particles with each ajax reload.  Any ideas?

Here is the canvas fork I created and am working with.

```
<div id="isohold">  
<canvas id="iso"></canvas>
<div id="loghold">Login</div>
</div>   

  <?php
    session_start();                
    //3.1.4 if the user is logged in Greets the user with message
    if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];


    echo " <script>

'use strict';


var rn = function rn(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
};
var ctx = iso.getContext('2d');

var _window = window;
var w = _window.innerWidth;
var h = _window.innerHeight;

var t = 10;
var arr = [];
var cn = 200;
var rad = 300;
var sp = rn(1, 5) / 10000;
iso.width = w;
iso.height = h;

while (~ ~ cn--) {
    var angle = rn(110, 359);

    arr = [].concat(arr, [{
        color: 'rgba(81, 180, 200, 0.5)',
        distortion: rn(15, 75),
        tmod: rn(5, 10),
        size: rn(15, 20),
        speed: 0.0005,
        angle: angle,
        lastPos: {
            x: w / 2,
            y: h / 2
        }
    }]);
}

var draw = function draw() {
    request = requestAnimationFrame(function () {
        return draw();
    });
    t++;

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0,.1)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

    var crad = rad * Math.sin(300);

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
    arr.forEach(function (el) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = el.color;
        ctx.lineWidth = el.size;
        ctx.beginPath();

        var lastPos = el.angle - 0.0005;
        var x = w / 2 + (crad + el.distortion * Math.sin(t / el.tmod)) * Math.cos(el.angle * 180 / Math.PI);
        var y = h / 2 + (crad + el.distortion * Math.sin(t / el.tmod)) * Math.sin(el.angle * 180 / Math.PI);

        ctx.moveTo(el.lastPos.x, el.lastPos.y);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);

        el.lastPos = { x: x, y: y };
        el.angle = (el.angle + 0.0005) % 359;
        ctx.stroke();
    });
};

var resize = function resize() {
    iso.width = w = window.innerWidth;
    iso.height = h = window.innerHeight;
};

var request = requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    return draw();
});
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    return resize();
});

</script>    
<script>
                 $(\"#loghold\").hide();   
</script>       
            ";
    }else{
    echo "<script>

'use strict';

var rn = function rn(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
};
var ctx = iso.getContext('2d');

var _window = window;
var w = _window.innerWidth;
var h = _window.innerHeight;

var t = 10;
var arr = [];
var cn = 200;
var rad = 300;

iso.width = w;
iso.height = h;

while (~ ~ cn--) {
    var angle = rn(110, 359);

    arr = [].concat(arr, [{
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
        distortion: rn(15, 75),
        tmod: rn(5, 10),
        size: rn(15, 20),
        speed: rn(1, 5) / 5000,
        angle: angle,
        lastPos: {
            x: w / 2,
            y: h / 2
        }
    }]);
}

var draw = function draw() {
    request = requestAnimationFrame(function () {
        return draw();
    });
    t++;

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0,.1)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

    var crad = rad * Math.sin(300);

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
    arr.forEach(function (el) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = el.color;
        ctx.lineWidth = el.size;
        ctx.beginPath();

        var lastPos = el.angle - el.speed;
        var x = w / 2 + (crad + el.distortion * Math.sin(t / el.tmod)) * Math.cos(el.angle * 180 / Math.PI);
        var y = h / 2 + (crad + el.distortion * Math.sin(t / el.tmod)) * Math.sin(el.angle * 180 / Math.PI);

        ctx.moveTo(el.lastPos.x, el.lastPos.y);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);

        el.lastPos = { x: x, y: y };
        el.angle = (el.angle + el.speed) % 359;
        ctx.stroke();
    });
};

var resize = function resize() {
    iso.width = w = window.innerWidth;
    iso.height = h = window.innerHeight;
};

var request = requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    return draw();
});
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    return resize();
});

</script>          
            ";           


  };

 ?>
```

ajax in php

```
 echo "  <script>


    $(\"#isoholder\").load(\"/iso/iso.php\");     


 </script>";
```

Comment: Could you also provide the ajax code and the part where you replace part of your document when you get the response?

Comment: Just edited in the ajax at the bottom trincot

Comment: the isoholder id is a div based on the main page, the first segment of code with the canvas is loaded into the isoholder div, and the ajax in the echo is from another div that loads when a login happens calling the .load to be fired.  I tried a work around of a clear function in an intermediary page that loads but to no avail

Comment: The problem seems that you are loading JavaScript into that div, script that is very similar to that which is already on the page. That gets executed on top of what is already running there. So you will have two separate stacks calling `requestAnimationFrame`, .... etc. This could be responsible for the speedup you see.

Comment: I agree with with you, it seems to be adding the speed variable from the first iteration ontop of the second, do you have any suggestions to prevent this?  I have attempted to rename the draw and request vars without luck

Comment: The URL you provide in the load should better get an argument like `\"/iso/iso.php?reload=1\"`, so that in PHP you can differentiate between a full page load and a load of the isoload div only. In that latter case PHP should not reproduce that div again, neither all the JavaScript. Instead it should only spit out a very small script that calls some init function already present on the page which you can provide the colour to.

Comment: This is probably poor form but do you have any references that might show an example of this?  I am looking but I can not find any to get an idea of how to do this.  Thank you for the time you've already spent in clarifying

Comment: I would in fact suggest not to load HTML/Javascript content like that. Instead dedicate a separate PHP file that just does the logon and answers with (outputs) a plain text "OK", "NOK". This never gets displayed, as you would process it in an $.ajax success handler, where you can check  this response and then change colours and such in script that is already there.

Answer (score 0):

Change the page to have the javascript for animation outside the session condition and in the session code just flag via a global var that you are logged in

```
  ... page data
  <script>
    // the following var must be global to the page.
    var sessionLoggedIn = false; // use this to determine the colours to use
    // the code to do the animation
    ...
    function draw(){
       if(sessionLoggedIn){ // if true then logged in 

       }else{ // not logged in

       }

    }
  </script>
  <?php
    session_start();                
    if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
        $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
        echo " <script> sessionLoggedIn = true;</script> ";
    }else{
        echo "<script> sessionLoggedIn = false;</script> ";
    }
  ?>
```